# Accessing image path in Cloud9 Amazon Web Services

Tags: html, image, amazon-web-services, express, aws-cloud9

I'm having trouble accessing an image in cloud9 on AWS.

Here's what I've got:

[Screenshot of file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wors.png)

This is what I currently have:

```
<img src="/flexbox/images/img1.jpg">
```

This doesn't work. The html file is here:

```
/flexbox/views/index.ejs
```

I've also tried

`<img src="../flexbox/images/img1.jpg">` and `<img src="../../flexbox/images/img1.jpg">`

I'd really appreciate someone explaining to me how to access the file. 
For further info I'm using node and express.

Thanks,

Raph

Comment: what is the url you used when the code show up

Comment: Hi, I didn't use a url to make the code show up, I highglighted the text then pressed the {} button... is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a simple pathing issue. Where is your HTML file in relation to `img1.jpg`? I don't see the HTML file in your screenshot.